# why are interaction frames abbreviated with "sd"?

Tags: uml

in UML2.0 comes frames for the contents area can be surrounded with frame and a heading
activity diagram **act**

class diagram  **class**

component diagram  **cmp**

interaction diagram  **sd**

package  **pkg**

state machine diagram  **stm**

use case diagram  **uc**

why are interaction frames abbreviated with "sd"?
and interaction diagram  **sd**  all interaction coming from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good point. For me sd was for sequence diagram only but according to UML 2.5 specification and more particularly section 17.2.4 it seems to be also the case for Communication Diagrams, Interaction Overview Diagrams, and Timing Diagrams.

> **17.2.4 Notation**
>
> **Interaction**
>
> The notation for an Interaction in a Sequence Diagram is a solid-outline rectangle. A pentagon in the upper left corner of the rectangle contains ‘sd’ followed by the Interaction name and parameters. The notation within this rectangular frame comes in several forms: Sequence Diagrams, Communication Diagrams, Interaction Overview Diagrams, and Timing Diagrams.

Comment: it's helpful answer